# The col-md-4 class in my code isnt formatting correctly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a PHP class with HTML code displaying three cards in a row in a column. When I add over 8 items onto the page it formats incorrectly i.e. it will put three in a row which it is meant to then put 1 then put 3 more etc (see attached image). Unsure why this is happening.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="card profile-card-2">

      <div class="card-img-block">
        <?php echo'<img class="img-fluid" src="data:image/jpg;base64,' . base64_encode( $results['image'] ) . '"  />' ?>
      </div>

      <div class="card-body pt-5">
        <h5 class="card-title"><?php echo $results['name']?></h5>
        <h5 class="card-text"><?php echo "Event Attended: ".$results['event_attended']." "?></h5>
        <h5 class="card-text"><?php echo "Charity: ".$results['charity_name']." "?></h5>
        <p class="card-text"><?php echo $results['feedback']?></p>
      </div>

      <div class="w3-half event">
        <button class="myBtn btn btn-primary">Read More</button>
        <div id="myModal" class="modal details-modal" class="modal-fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
          <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">

            <!-- Modal content -->
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <h2 class="modal-title"><?php ?></h2>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                <h3>Event Description </h3>
                <h5 class="card-title"><?php echo $results['name']?></h5>
                <h5 class="card-text"><?php echo "Event Attended: ".$results['event_attended']." "?></h5>
                <h5 class="card-text"><?php echo "Charity: ".$results['charity_name']." "?></h5>
                <hr>
                <p><?php echo $results['feedback'] ?><br></p>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

It is meant to display 3 in a row and start a new row where need be

[image]

Comment: You are supposed to use `col-*` classes inside a `row` div

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap?

Comment: @j08691 yeah i am